# Use standard WordPress categories with a CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I've just converted all of my blog posts to a CPT because I needed them to be hierarchical.  Problem is, I had categories assigned to all of the posts. How can I use the standard WordPress categories in my CPT?

I've tried adding `'taxonomies' => array('category'),` to the `register_post_type` function, but that didn't work. And I tried `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'illustrations' )` and that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:   Thanks all for the replies but as mentioned above — I've tried both `'taxonomies' => array('category')` and `'taxonomies' => array('category'),` and neither have worked.

Here's the whole register_post_type function — with the 'taxonomies' parameter:

```
/* Register the 'Illustrations' post type */

register_post_type(
    'illustrations',
    array(
        'label' => 'illustrations',
        'description' => '',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/images/help-icon.png',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '' ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'revisions', 'comments','author' ),
        'labels' => array (
            'name' => 'Illustrations',
            'singular_name' => 'Illustration',
            'menu_name' => 'Illustrations',
            'add_new' => 'Add Illustration',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add new Illustration',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit illustration',
            'new_item' => 'New illustration',
            'view' => 'View illustration',
            'view_item' => 'View illustration',
            'search_items' => 'Search illustrations',
            'not_found' => 'No Illustrations Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Illustrations Found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Illustration',
            ), ) );

register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'illustrations' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type). Very simple usage.

You could also try passing the 'taxonomies' argument in your `register_post_type`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply — but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You're doing the registration on the `init` hook, correct?

Comment: ACK! That got deleted and I never noticed. Thanks so much for the help — once I had that part in there, everything worked out A-ok.

Answer (score 4):

By default the queries for category pages will only query the `post` post type, so in addition to registering the post type with category in the taxonomies argument, you have to modify those queries via [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to get the CPT to appear on category pages:

```
function wpa_illustrations_on_category_pages( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'illustrations' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_illustrations_on_category_pages' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
    /** Add Custom Taxonomy **/
    function illustrations_category_taxonomy() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => __( 'Categories' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Category' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'hierarchical'      => true
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'illustrations-category', 'illustrations', $args );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'illustrations_category_taxonomy');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `taxonomies argument` like this:

```
    'taxonomies' => array('category')
```

In your `register_post_type` code.

Additional information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

---

**Update:**

```
/* Register the 'Illustrations' post type */

    add_action( 'init', 'wpse114838_reg_pt_illustrations');
    function wpse114838_reg_pt_illustrations() { 
        register_post_type(
            'illustrations',
            array(
                'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'Illustrations',
                'singular_name' => 'Illustration',
                'menu_name' => 'Illustrations',
                'add_new' => 'Add Illustration',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add new Illustration',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit illustration',
                'new_item' => 'New illustration',
                'view' => 'View illustration',
                'view_item' => 'View illustration',
                'search_items' => 'Search illustrations',
                'not_found' => 'No Illustrations Found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Illustrations Found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Illustration',
                ),
                'label' => 'illustrations',
                'description' => '',
                'public' => true,
                'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/images/help-icon.png',
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                //you need just one of the methods, uncomment the one you want
                //'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '' ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'revisions', 'comments','author' ),
            )
        );
        //you need just one of the methods, uncomment the one you want    
        //register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'illustrations' );
    }
```

This is based on the code in your question. I tested it, with both - `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'illustrations' );` or `'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )` - methods, and it's working. Just use one of them, there is no sense in doing both, uncomment the one you want in the code above. You probably didn't hook into the init action, like @EricHolmes and @Howdy_McGee suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply — but this doesn't seem to work for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: Just to follow up on this, the revised answer is certainly working.