# How to Add Custom Taxonomy To Woocommerce Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, plugins

I am trying to add a Custom Taxonomy to Woocommerce by targeting the product post type in Woocommerce. I used following code and added it into `functions.php` I am not getting any error message but the taxonomy is not showing in the Woocommerce as well. Can you please let me know how I can do this or what I am doing wrong here?

```
<?php
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy_Item()  {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Items',
    'singular_name'              => 'Item',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Item',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Item with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Items',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Items',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );
}
?>
```

**Update**

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_Item' );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy_Item()  {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Items',
    'singular_name'              => 'Item',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Item',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Item with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Items',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Items',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product', $args );

}
?>
```

Comment: what action have you hooked your `custom_taxonomy_Item` function to?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know what action to hook? I couldnt find which part of plugin in handling this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to do:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_Item' );
```

Because:

> Use the init action to call this function. Calling it outside of an action can lead to troubles.

see codex page [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). Besides that :

> Better **be safe than sorry** when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use [register_taxonomy_for_object_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) right after the function to interconnect them. Else you could run into minetraps where the post type isn't attached inside filter callback that run during `parse_request` or `pre_get_posts`.

So better add:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );
```

Additionally to reading the linked codex pages you could take a look at:

- [Use standard WordPress categories with a CPT](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/114838/22534)

All this together should get you started.

---

**Edit:**

Like I said in the comment, it's working for me, this is the **Code:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_Item' );
function custom_taxonomy_Item()  {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => __('Items'),
        'singular_name'              => __('Item'),
        'menu_name'                  => __('Items'),
        'all_items'                  => __('All Items'),
        'parent_item'                => __('Parent Item'),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __('Parent Item:'),
        'new_item_name'              => __('New Item Name'),
        'add_new_item'               => __('Add New Item'),
        'edit_item'                  => __('Edit Item'),
        'update_item'                => __('Update Item'),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate Item with commas'),
        'search_items'               => __('Search Items'),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Add or remove Items'),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from the most used Items'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );
}
```

Comment: Hi ialocin, thanks for your comment and hints.I updated the code code as I posted on the top but "Item" still not showing in Woocomerce Menu

Comment: You have to **add** `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` and **not** replace `register_taxonomy`. It's working on my development environment. BTW [product attributes](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/) are custom taxonomies too. @user1760110

Comment: That's strange ! it is not working for me

Comment: thanks it works now BUT, it is not adding any Term to the product. if you click on the Item and try to add new Item it is not doing any thing!

Comment: Can't confirm this, it' working fine for me. @user1760110

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I am going to accept your comment as correct answer, however I have to figure out why it is not adding terms!

Comment: @user1760110 I'm having the same problem, the code above isn't adding new terms for me, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: +1 on register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );

Comment: Worked perfectly after adding both lines `register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );`