# Basic CPT Question About Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Missing something basic here. Here's my CPT code...

```
// Create a custom post type
//
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_func' );
function custom_post_type_func() {
    //posttypename = PDSH Posts
    $labels = array (
    'name' => _x( 'PDSH Posts', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'PDSH Post', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New PDSH Post', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit PDSH Post', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New PDSH Post', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View PDSH Post', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search PDSH Posts', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No PDSH Posts found', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No PDSH Posts found in Trash', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent PDSH Post:', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'PDSH Posts', 'pdsh_posts' ),
    );
    $args = array (
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'Hi, this is my custom post type.',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'pdsh_posts', $args );
}
```

Works great!
I'm using the WP All Import plugin to create 3378 PDSH Posts with three parent categories: Alphabetical, Creators, Morality. They all look correctly populated here...
[image]
But when I view one of those categories the archive page can't see the posts, goes to content-none, throws up a Not Found.
Do I need to register all 106 categories somehow, or maybe just the three parent categories?

Updated:

Here's my attempt to register "Alphabetical" and "A"...

```
//
// Hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
// 
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
// Create a custom taxonomy name it subjects for your posts
function create_post_types_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
    // //first do the translations part for GUI
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Alphabetical', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Alphabetical', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Alphabetical' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Alphabetical' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Alphabetical' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Alphabetical:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Alphabetical' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Alphabetical' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Alphabetical' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Alphabetical Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Alphabetical' ),
  );
    // Now register the taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('Alphabetical',array('A'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Alphabetical' ),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings -> Permalinks to flush them?

Comment: Yes, a bunch of times.

Comment: Yes, you have to register the taxonomies.

Comment: I tried the code in this article: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/ under "Creating a Hierarchical Taxonomy". Maybe I interpreted the instructions incorrectly? I suppose I need to register both "Alphabetical" and "A"?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add in your `register_taxonomy` code?

Comment: Added. Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: If you want to use the default category taxonomy with your cpr, then my edited answer might help. On the other hand, if you want to create custom taxonomies for the cpt, the you need to register them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>It might just be the late hours, but the `register_taxonomy` call looks wrong. Shouldn't the second parameter be the post type you're registering the taxonomy for? I.e. `array('pdsh_posts')`.</del>

<del>And yes, you need to register each of the three taxonomies separately for the post type.</del>

<del>See the codex example, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#comment-397</del>

**Edit**

Actually, its probably not what I wrote above. Registering the cpt with the default `category` taxonomy, if that is what you want to use, should only need the following parameter for the cpt

`'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),`

The reason why you're getting not found on the category view is that by default the Loop only looks for posts, not your cpts'. You'll need to add the cpt to the query with `pre_get_posts`

Example here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114853/144392

Comment: Thanks Antti. This works: function pdsh_posts_on_category_pages( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'pdsh_posts' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pdsh_posts_on_category_pages' );

Comment: Shouldn't archive-pdsh_posts.php work? I mean, shouldn't these post types default to that archive name instead of the normal one? It doesn't with or without this function.

Comment: @markw Yes, when viewing the custom post type post archive, i.e. when viewing all of the posts as a list. Not when trying to view cpts attached to a term from the default Category taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually getting archive and category mixed up, category-my-cpt.php works as expected, archive-my-cpt.php does not.